# Copy .txt to int array, then save into another file

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream, ofstream, dev-c++

// Edit : I've discovered my mistake. Still I'm missing 1 thing: It doesn't count lines correctly. If the last char in .txt isnt '\n' it counts 1 less line. If I hit it it counts 2 much. What's wrong ? Can you help me?

> krol.txt =

```
2 4
3 7
3 13
2 4
3 1
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ofstream outFile;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("krol.txt");
    int l=0;
    char ch;
    while (fin.good()){
        fin.get(ch);
        if (ch=='\n') l++;
    }
    cout << l;
    fin.close();
    fin.open("krol.txt");
    int temp[l][2];
    int savel=l;
    l=0;
    int i=0;
        while (fin >> (temp[l][i])){
        i++;
        if(i==2){ 
         i=0; l++;
        }
    }

    outFile.open("save.txt");
    for (int i=0, j=0;j<savel;i++){
        if (i==2) {
        i=0; j++;
        }
        outFile << temp[j][i];
    }
    outFile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Writing binary data to a text file is a no-no.

Comment: That code would *NEVER* compile. Brace mismatches, fout undeclared etc. etc. Please post 'real' code.

Comment: oh! I pasted wrong code. I'm sorry about that. its corrected now

Comment: You are trying to save into the array int temp[l][2] - which can contain 1*2 ints 5* 2 ints from you file. Don`t you think that this is strange, you should adjust you file or size of you array. So in case of array: temp[5][2] - but of course I think that it is very bad practice to use hardcoded numbers

Comment: File has to look like array[x][y] where y - const int y=2;

Comment: If you define a struct with two ints and then just use std::vector of those structs, you won't need to count the lines in advance. And, all that horrible `if (i==2)` stuff disappears.

Comment: @spin_eight: It's 'l', not '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no C++ expert, but shouldn't

```
fout >> ch;
```

be

```
fout << ch;
```

?

(Fixed from Thomas Matthews' comment)

Comment: actually, `fin >> ch' might be what he means?

Comment: I did mistake about pasting wrong code (uncorrected). Now I edited it to compile-able code.

Comment: If its output, it would be `fout << ch;`